# Inner aggregated interface not accessible

Tags: com, aggregation

I instantiate a 64 bit COM server(m_pServer an OUT of proc ...also the outer object in this case) from 32 bit application. But when I try to access the 64 bit inner object (m_InnerCtrl ) in my 32 bit application, its unable to either perform the marshaling or something else that i am not aware of.

```
hr = m_pServer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Server), NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER);//64 bit from 32 bit

m_InnerCtrl = m_pServer;// this does not initialize the inner
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. What are the types of `m_pServer` and `m_InnerCtrl`? Are they COM/ATL smart pointers? If so, then the second line of code there should be performing a `QueryInterface`. Is the interface for `m_InnerCtrl` proxyable?

Comment: Yes they are smart pointers IUnknownPtr m_pServer; IInnerCtrlPtr m_InnerCtrl; ..No I dont need do a QI on the outer, it works alrite in 32bit vesion.

Comment: The `=` operator performs the `QueryInterface` automatically. Has the `IInnerCtrl` interface been registered so that it is proxyable in both a 64-bit and 32-bit process? One thing to try is to manually perform the QI on `m_pServer` and see what `HRESULT` you get back.

Comment: BEGIN_COM_MAP(Server)COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AUTOAGGREGATE_BLIND(m_pUnkInnerCtrl.p, __uuidof(InnerCtrl))

Comment: How are you implementing the proxy/stub? A separate DLL? Merged into the same DLL? Is the proxy/stub being registered?

Comment: i did a manually QI. Got interface not supported or something similar. wat does the term proxyable mean. Offcourse both version of 32 and 64 bit are registered..verified in registry

Comment: Then inner component is a com dll that is loaded in the 64 bit out of proc server. Just saw the code, the support for merging of stubs and proxies is there in the code, but the PreProcesor tag is missing to enable it .Do u think it is needed..?

Comment: A proxy/stub is _definitely_ needed for an interface to work in inter-apartment, inter-process or inter-machine scenarios. The exact HRESULT that comes from the QI might give you some more information on whether the p/s is the problem. See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an interface to be used between apartments, between processes, or between machines, the interface must have a proxy/stub implementation. `IUnknown` comes with a default proxy/stub implementation. Therefore, you can get the `IUnknown` for any class which can be instantiated out-of-proc. However, if your custom interface does not have a proxy/stub, you will not be able to QI for that interface because COM won't know how to proxy that interface.

There are a handful of default proxy/stub implementations for known COM scenarios (automation, for example), but a) they don't always work, depending on how your interface is defined, b) depending on the registration mechanism you're using, they don't always get registered, and c) in some scenarios, the out-of-the-box proxy/stubs don't perform as well as a proxy/stub that is hardcoded according to the specific interface that it is for. I usually prefer to build my own proxy/stub using the code that is auto-generated from IDL. This produces the most widely-usable and highest-performing proxy/stub implementation.

Unfortunately, I cannot concisely instruct you on how to build and register the proxy/stub, as it is a complex topic, and the exact steps would depend on the current state of your project and how it got into that state. I suggest you read up on COM proxy/stub implementations and how it relates to IDL and ATL. If you start a new ATL project using VC++ and add an object to it, you'll find that some of the options in the Project wizard or New Object wizard are specifically for setting up the proxy.

One exercise that I found useful when learning this: Create multiple projects with different options selected in the wizards, and then use a diff tool to compare the projects to see the effect that the options have on each project.

Comment: Thanks. I will try out the things u have mentioned . Appreciate the time that u put in for a detailed answer ! cheers

Comment: Another suggestion: The proxy/stub itself is another COM class that implements both the custom interface and a handful of additional interfaces specifically for initializing it as a proxy/stub. Since it's a COM class, it can be directly instantiated just like any other. The CLSID for the proxy/stub class is put into the registry, as a subkey of the interface registry entry. Find the 32-bit registry entry (within Wow6432Node) for your custom interface. Verify that it has a ProxyStubClsid32 subkey. Then try to instantiate that CLSID directly from within the 32-bit process.

Comment: I tried the PS stuff with a sample application. A 32 bit test client that will instantiate a 64 bit test out of proc server which houses a 64 bit inner interface. But it didnt work. I tried both the options of>>allow merging of proxy and stubs and create a separate PS project.. Also verified if the ProxyStubClsid32 subkey was there, still to no avail. Is there any place i can put up the sample code for inspection !

Comment: Got my sample projects to work..When choosing threading model chose as BOTH  for outof proc and the innerobject as well. Dont know if that had any effect ...Earlier ..was using FREE

Comment: Hmmm. I can't think of why that would have any effect. The proxy/stub must support both threading models because the proxy will be created in the same apartment/process/machine in which the client code is running. The stub (it's the same class as the proxy) will be created in the same apartment as the server object. Both the out-of-the-box proxy/stubs and the p/s built from the auto-generated code work in either threading model and support a server object that uses either threading model. But if you've got something that works, you may be onto something.